# Dart polymer Paper_elements don't play nicely with sample webapp when compiled to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dart, polymer, dart-polymer, dart2js

I have problem using paper_element in dart polymer app.

Dart Editor version 1.5.8.release (STABLE)
Dart SDK version 1.5.8

I create sample web application with polymer. 
I add following dependencies to pubspec.yaml

```
polymer: ">=0.12.0 <0.13.0"
core_elements: ">=0.1.0 <0.2.0"
paper_elements: ">=0.1.0 <0.2.0"
```

These are versions pub downloads:

```
polymer 0.12.0
core_elements 0.1.1+2
paper_elements 0.1.0+3
```

I import paper_elements in main html file

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">
```

and then run it as Javascript.

In resulting page Click counter component doesn't show up and following error appears in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined
http://127.0.0.1:8080/demo3.html_bootstrap.dart.js
```

I tested it in IE11 and Chrome36.
In Dartium everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same on Dart SDK version 1.6.0-dev.6.0 but only when I import paper_input.html from paper_elements. Try to file a bug!